# Error: no strategy registered under name: google

Tags: node.js

I'm new to `nodeJs` and i am using `passport authentication` via google  and getting error . I have written my code in different module .  Before posting I have gone through the Jared Hanson reply.. and write the verify callback as an argument to the strategy constructor,but still getting the error.

```
Error: no strategy registered under name: google
    at attempt (C:\Users\nidhish\Documents\GitHub\KinoCards\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\middleware\authenticate.js:237:37)
    at Passport.authenticate (C:\Users\nidhish\Documents\GitHub\KinoCards\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\middleware\authenticate.js:244:7)
    at callbacks (C:\Users\nidhish\Documents\GitHub\KinoCards\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:161:37)
    at param (C:\Users\nidhish\Documents\GitHub\KinoCards\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
    at pass (C:\Users\nidhish\Documents\GitHub\KinoCards\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (C:\Users\nidhish\Documents\GitHub\KinoCards\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (C:\Users\nidhish\Documents\GitHub\KinoCards\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
    at Context.next (C:\Users\nidhish\Documents\GitHub\KinoCards\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
    at Context.actions.pass (C:\Users\nidhish\Documents\GitHub\KinoCards\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\context\http\actions.js:77:8)
    at SessionStrategy.authenticate (C:\Users\nidhish\Documents\GitHub\KinoCards\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\strategies\session.js:67:10)
```

Comment: you need show some code

Comment: you probably didn't include the passport-google module. hard to say without code though...

Comment: I have divided my code in module:- app.get('/auth/google',
        passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/index' }),
        function(req, res) {
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    app.get('/auth/google/return',
        passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/index' }),
        function(req, res) {
            res.redirect('/');
        });

Comment: module.exports = function (passport, config) {
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
            returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/return',
            realm: 'http://localhost:3000/'
        },function(identifier, profile, done){          
            process.nextTick(function () {
           profile.identifier = identifier;
                return done(null, profile);